# option of select element is empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I have a list of products in a select2 element. It displays like this:

```
    <select name="product" class="select2 form-control select2-hidden-accessible">
        <option value="138" data-select2-id="60">Option1</option>
        <option value="39" data-select2-id="78">Option2</option>
        // several more options here
     </select>
```

Even though this looks correct, when I iterate over the options like this:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    console.log(select.options[i]);
}
```

I get 1 and only 1 (even though there are several options) log entry of an empty option element like:

```
<option value="" selected="" data-select2-id="8">
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Edit1: I have several selects in the same page all using the same function that iterates through the options. This is the only one I'm having problems with.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code:

In this statement `select.options.length`, `select` is not a valid selector or variable (based on the code you've given in the question). It will give you a select is undefined error.

Switch your for loop to this:

```
var dropDown = document.querySelector('.select2');
for (let i = 0; i < dropDown.options.length; i++) {
    console.log(dropDown.options[i]);
}
```

This will display both options.

Comment: Hi, select is a valid element. I send it to the function as a parameter. If I log "select" then I see the correctly rendered select element.

Comment: It is a valid element but it needs to be wrapped inside a ```document.querySelector``` or ```document.getElementsByTagName``` or something. You can directly reference select. Did the above code not work for you?

Comment: This is the only select element I'm having problems with. The other selects I send to the functions in the same way and those work perfectly well.

Comment: That's odd. Print out the length of your select and see if the for loop is iterating 2 times.

Comment: The lenght of the problematic select is always 1 allthough there are several options in it. The other selects (all used with the same code) return the correct length.

Comment: Possible to add a jsfiddle or codepen showing the issue?

Comment: @jaimish11 You should ask for a Stack Snippet, not jsfiddle or codepen. We prefer to keep the code here when possible.

Comment: I just coded a jsfiddle but its working as expected there... So it doesn't really make sense I guess?

Comment: Same class, id and name attributes there?

Comment: I just looked at your code. For loop seems to be running correctly. There has to be something different in your production code.

Comment: Production code is identical but with different option texts